# Wrong Size-Class of UIViewController shown with UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, size-classes

I am working on universal iPhone/iPad application with universal storyboard. For some ViewControllers I'm using size classes if they has some specific layout on iPad.

I have one ViewController that needs to be presented modally on iPhone but on iPad it needs to be shown in UIPopoverController.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ComposeMessageNavigationController"];
ComposeMessageViewController *viewController = (ComposeMessageViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
//Prepeare my view controlller
...

if (IS_IPAD) {
    UIPopoverController * popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGRect popoverFrame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2, 1, 1);
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
} else {
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

It works pretty good but there is problem with Size Classes. I made some changes on storyboard at wRegular/hRegular Size Class but on iPad in UIPopoverController still showing iPhone layout. It's because of size of popover is lower then iPad screen. Can I make my changes in Interface Builder with Size Classes to show them in popover on iPad but ignore on iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Using setOverrideTraitCollection on the popover view controller should allow you to use the regular x regular for an iPad.